# How to access the MS Outlook mail using the EntryIDCollection?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-2010

I am reading Outlook mail using this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
int i = myInbox.Items.Count;
string strSubject = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).Subject;
string senderEmailid = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).SenderEmailAddress;
string ToEmailid = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).To;
string CcEmailid = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).CC;
string BccEmailid = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).BCC;
string CreationTime = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).CreationTime.ToString();
```

I am getting `EntryIDCollection` as well. How can I read the mail using `EntryIDCollection` instead of mail count i.e. `i` in my code?

I am using MS Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Namespace.GetItemFromID`